# Find the time difference and group the time gap

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
yt1.[timestamp] AS StartTime,
MIN(yt2.[timestamp]) AS EndTime,
DATEDIFF(s, yt1.[timestamp], MIN(yt2.[timestamp])) AS DifferenceInSeconds
FROM
yourTable yt1
LEFT JOIN yt2 ON yt1.[timestamp] < yt2.[timestamp]
WHERE
yt1.Col1 IS NULL
OR yt1.Col2 IS NULL
...
OR yt1.Col20 IS NULL
OR yt2.Col1 IS NULL
...
OR yt2.Col20 IS NULL 
GROUP BY yt1.[timestamp]
```

On the same query , the current output is like

```
18-05-2012 20:07
18-05-2012 20:17
18-05-2012 20:27
18-05-2012 20:37
```

etc are having 10 min gaps, consecutive gaps we should see 18-05-2012 20:07 as start time and 18-05-2012 20:37 as end time and gap in minutes 40. Can you please help

Comment: You question is not clear.  The query has three columns but you give the output only as a single column.  Can you provide what output you are getting and what you want?  The explanation is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry. The output contains

Comment: 18-05-2012 20:07 10
18-05-2012 20:17 10
18-05-2012 20:27 10
18-05-2012 20:37 10 i need the output as 18-05-2012 20:07 18-05-2012 20:37 40 as all time gaps are having 10. please let me know i am not clear